# Why does urxvt appear different when run through x-terminal-emulator?

Tags: x11, rxvt, x-resources

When `urxvt` is launched directly a nice looking font is used:

[image: plain]

But when it is launched by `x-terminal-emulator` an ugly cramped font is used:

[image: through x-terminal-emulator]

But `x-terminal-emulator` is just a symlink which eventually resolves to `/usr/bin/urxvt`:

```
ls /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -l         
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jun 19  2016 /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -> /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator

ls /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Mar 16 08:14 /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator -> /usr/bin/urxvt
```

and

```
which urxvt
/usr/bin/urxvt
```

If it matters I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, with urxvt version 9.21.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably seeing the symbolic link as an alias which changes the *instance name*, and using that as a (mis)clue is missing the X resource file (and using just its fallback resources).

Comment: Yes! Thank you! It turns out that my font settings were `urxvt*font: ...` but it should have been `URxvt*font: ...`. For any future bug hunters: from what I can understand in Xresource configuration `urxvt` is a program name, so it doesn't apply when the `$0` is anything other `urxvt` (e.g. when it's `x-terminal-emulator`). In contrast `URxvt` is a "class" name so it applies for all programs.

Answer (score 0):

After googling without no help (everyone indicates use of `URxvt` on `Xresources` but on mine only works as `urxvt`) I supposed that it follows the instance name that is derived from the start process.

I tried in `.Xresources`:

```
x-terminal-emulator*font: xft:Victor Mono:pixelsize=16
```

And then ran `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`

It worked.

Observe that I don't know if this is the best way. It worked. And I think that use the `x-terminal-emulator` when calling a terminal is a more standard way through many desktop environments.